# Angular 4 scroll to element in the list at the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, angular, scrollview

I have *ngFor list with items inside a scrollable div, on key down I am selecting the item, what I am trying to achieve is only when I am at the bottom of the page I want to scroll the div.

message.component.html

```html
<div class="message-list" tabindex="0"
     *ngFor="let message of messages;  let i=index" id="{{i}}"
     [ngClass]="{'message-list-active': activeIndex === i  }>
  message
</div>
```

message.component.ts

```js
if (event.key === "Down"  && this.activeIndex < this.messages.length - 1) {
  this.activeIndex++
  let str = this.activeIndex
  var elmnt = document.getElementById(str.toString());
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
```

The issue is it scrolls when I click down, but I need it to only scroll when I am at the bottom of the page.
I got the behaviour with scrollIntoViewIfNeeded, it works perfect, but scrollIntoViewIfNeeded is not supported in IE, so looks like need to use scrollIntoView

[scrollList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAhoQ.png)

Comment: So you want to scroll down when you select an item at the bottom of the list?

Comment: yes when I am at the bottom of the list I want to scoll